# How do I override a Panel's minimum size?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm trying to implement a panel subclass that will automatically insert vertical scrollbars if the content overflows its vertical bounds. I want the panel to work **exactly** like a normal panel in every respect but one: Instead of the minimum height of the panel being the minimum height of its sizer, it should have a static value (like 200), and when the height of the panel is lower than the height of its sizer, a vertical scrollbar should appear. In other words, when the height of the panel is *higher* than that minimum height of the sizer, it should function exactly like a normal panel.

The issue I'm having is that overriding functions like `DoGetBestSize` and `GetMinSize` on the panel is having no effect, as those functions are never called (I checked by inserting breakpoints). I'm guessing the panel's parent is communicating directly with the panel's sizer, which in this case is a normal box sizer set from outside the panel.

```
class ScrolledPanel(wx.Panel):
    """A panel that will automatically add scrollbars when needed."""

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)

        self.SetBackgroundColour('#FF0000')

    # This function is never called.
    def DoGetBestSize(self):
        """Override the minimum size of the panel."""

        default = self.GetSizer().GetMinSize()
        default.SetHeight(250)

        return default
```

Is it possible to achieve the effect I'm after? If so, how do I circumvent the problem described above?

[Here is the code in which I'm trying to use the scrolled panel](http://pastebin.com/XJi13Zge).

---

#### Update

I thought I'd try to override the `SetSizer` function, take that sizer hostage and consult it regarding sizes, but not actually setting the sizer on the panel. That way the custom size functions like `DoGetBestSize` would be called. It failed though. Even though no sizer has been set, those functions are still never called. I've tried both `Panel` and `PyPanel`. Here is my current scroll panel:

```
class ScrolledPanel(wx.PyPanel):
    """A panel that will automatically add scrollbars when needed."""

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)

        self.SetBackgroundColour('#FF0000')

    # This function is called.
    def SetSizer(self, sizer):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        self._pet_sizer = sizer

    # The below functions are never called.
    def DoGetBestSize(self):
        """Override the minimum size of the panel."""
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        default = self.GetSizer().GetMinSize()
        default.SetHeight(250)

        return default

    def DoGetClientSize(self):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

    def DoGetSize(self):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

    def DoGetVirtualSize(self):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Answer (score 2):

Overriding methods in wxPython currently requires using base classes that are designed to reflect some of the calls to C++ virtuals to the overridden methods in Python.  That means that if you want to catch those in a panel you need to derive your class from wx.PyPanel instead of wx.Panel. See http://wiki.wxpython.org/OverridingMethods

Answer (score 0):

Why are you reinventing the wheel? wxPython provides a ScrolledPanel widget: 
wx.lib.scrolledpanel

You should just use that. The wxPython demo has an example.

**EDIT: Here's an example script with a scrolledPanel inside a sizer.**

```
import wx
import  wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

########################################################################
class MyScrolledPanel(scrolled.ScrolledPanel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        scrolled.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent)


########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        text = "one two buckle my shoe three four shut the door five six pick up sticks seven eight lay them straight nine ten big fat hen"

        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sPanel = MyScrolledPanel(self)

        words = text.split()
        for word in words:
            hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
            label = wx.StaticText(sPanel, -1, word+":")
            tc = wx.TextCtrl(sPanel, -1, word, size=(50,-1))

            hSizer.Add(label, flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.LEFT, border=10)
            hSizer.Add(tc, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
            sizer.Add(hSizer)

        sPanel.SetSizer(sizer)
        sPanel.SetAutoLayout(1)
        sPanel.SetupScrolling()

        mainSizer.Add(sPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)


########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        panel = MainPanel(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I'm not reinventing the wheel, I'm trying to improve it. `wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel` needs to have a fixed position and size to work. When I put it in a sizer it starts acting just like a normal panel.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing, but I can get a scrolledPanel to work just fine inside a sizer. It does not require a fixed position or size. I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special. If you call `SetVirtualSize()` on any `wxWindow`, including `wxPanel`, it already will show scrollbars as needed and the sizers will use the virtual size to lay out this window contents.

Comment: -1 This is incorrect. Setting a virtual size will affect the layout of the controls, but it will never spawn scroll bars.

Comment: This is definitely correct, this is how `wxScrolledWindow` works. You probably need to call `SetScrollRate()` too however.

Comment: If that's how `wxScrolledWindow` works, what's the difference between a `wxPanel` and a `wxScrolledWindow`?

Comment: Not that much. The basic scrolling is implemented at `wxWindow` level in wxWidgets, `wxScrolledWindow` "just" adds convenient methods to configure it and update scrollbars.